# Checking the generated PDA against the user's PDA input

Tags: pda, account-data

First of all, I'm new to Solana development (came from an Ethereum background), so sorry if my question is too basic.
I'm following the `SolDev` course, I'm on course [state management](https://www.soldev.app/course/program-state-management). I have a confusion about section `Lab/5. DerivePDA`. It is said:

> Let’s independently derive the PDA we expect the user to have passed in

As far as I understood, the user provides the PDA for the account to be deployed at, in `accounts input`, and we try to recalculate the PDA to verify its correctness. However, I see no validation in the code provided in the course.

```
pub fn add_movie_review(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    title: String,
    rating: u8,
    description: String
) -> ProgramResult {

    // Get Account iterator
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Get accounts
    let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    // Derive PDA
    let (pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[initializer.key.as_ref(), title.as_bytes().as_ref(),], program_id);

     // QUESTION: why not check the calculated `pda` against `pda_account`??
    
    // Calculate account size required
    let account_len: usize = 1 + 1 + (4 + title.len()) + (4 + description.len());

    // Calculate rent required
    let rent = Rent::get()?;
    let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(account_len);

    // Create the account
    invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            initializer.key,
            pda_account.key,
            rent_lamports,
            account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
            program_id,
        ),
        &[initializer.clone(), pda_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
        &[&[initializer.key.as_ref(), title.as_bytes().as_ref(), &[bump_seed]]],
    )?;

    msg!("PDA created: {}", pda);

    msg!("unpacking state account");
    let mut account_data = try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
    msg!("borrowed account data");

    account_data.title = title;
    account_data.rating = rating;
    account_data.description = description;
    account_data.is_initialized = true;

    msg!("serializing account");
    account_data.serialize(&mut &mut pda_account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
    msg!("state account serialized");

    Ok(())
}
```

If no check is required, then why do we try to re-calculate the PDA? I can see that the code uses the provided `pda_account` directly to create the new account here:

```
// Create the account
    invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            initializer.key,
            pda_account.key,
            rent_lamports,
            account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
            program_id,
        ),
        &[initializer.clone(), pda_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
        &[&[initializer.key.as_ref(), title.as_bytes().as_ref(), &[bump_seed]]],
    )?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing in the seeds to `invoke_signed`, the runtime will check to make sure that one of the accounts can be promoted to a signer using the provided seeds.

The runtime will perform `create_program_address` with those seeds, and then match it against all of the accounts provided to see which can become a signer.

There's actually a way to exploit the program do the wrong thing since it isn't checking the address, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader :-)